# Jquery и псевдокласс :after

Tags: jquery, css

Всем привет.

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли в Jquery селектор для обращения к элементам с псевдоклассом "after"?

Или как можно обратиться к такому элементу, чтобы поменяться CSS-свойство?

Comment: это даже не элементы а псевдоэлементы, недаром в css3 ввели это понятие и обозначение element::after дабы подчеркнуть отличие псевдоклассов (:hidden) от псевдоэлементов (::after)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Напрямую к псевдоэлементу обратиться нельзя, но можно изменять его свойства добавляя тот, или иной CSS-класс к основному элементу:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pnlTest"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#pnlTest
{
    width: 50px; height: 50px;
    background-color: black
}
#pnlTest:after
{
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: green;
    display: block;
    content: '';
}
#pnlTest.red:after 
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#pnlTest').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('red')
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('red')
});
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/RGWrq/

Answer (score 7):

Возможно я ошибаюсь, но можно только получить информацию:

```
var el = document.getElementById('my-elem');
var pseudoStyle = window.getComputedStyle(el, ':after');
```

А вот изменить можно только через css, добавляя нужный класс, либо генерировать правило "налету".

Answer (score 0):

Можно через переменную сделать.

```
.blk {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px; height: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  --inside-color: #003366;
}
       
.blk::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px; height: 24px;
  z-index: +2;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  right: 8px; top: calc(50% - 12px);
  background-color: var(--inside-color);
}
```

Потом у основного элемента менять CSS-свойство `--inside-color`, а псевдоэлемент его использует.