# Как применять действие в jquery к :after?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Пишу код такого плана но он не работает.

```js
  $(".mapopen").click(function() {
    $(".top_rightmenu ul li a:after").hide();
  });
```

Comment: возможно дубликат - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/229179/jquery-и-псевдокласс-after

Answer (score 1):

`:after` - это псевдоэлемент, на прямую из кода вы на него повлиять не сможете, только через родительский элемент

```
$(".mapopen").click(function() {
  $(".top_rightmenu ul li a").addClass('hide-after);
});
```

А в `css` пропишите

```
.top_rightmenu ul li a.hide-after:after {display:none}`
```

Что бы вернуть `:after` просто убирайте класс у ссылки

Comment: А как сделать действие по аналогу .toggle()? Чтобы при клике на ссылку класс добавлялся/удалялся?

Comment: Для этого используйте `.toggleClass('hide-after);` вместо `.addClass('hide-after);`