# Как попасть к элементу before в DOM js?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Как с помощью JS можно добраться до элемента before.
Например есть `div` а в нем `before` и надо изменить стили в `before` с помощью JS, как можно сделать?

Comment: Этот вопрос уже задавали в англоязычном Stackoverflow. Смотри тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061414/changing-width-property-of-a-before-css-selector-using-jquery/10061479

Comment: да и на рус тоже есть [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/229179/jquery-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-after)

Answer (score 0):

Можно только на чтение:

```js
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var f = getComputedStyle(header, "::before");

console.log(f.content);
```

```css
#header::before{
content: "Иван";
}
```

```html
<header id="header"> ?</header>
```